# c# подписать и зашифровать архив zip используя ГОСТ Р 34.11-2012, ГОСТ Р 34.10-2012

Tags: c#, шифрование, цифровая-подпись

Возможно ли подписать и зашифровать архив zip используя библиотеки на c# ?. Документации как работают эти алгоритмы много, а самой реализации библиотек не очень. Шифрование в формате CMS/PKCS#7 в DER кодировке

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону этой библиотеки https://github.com/AlexMAS/GostCryptography
работает хорошо, использую в проде. Доступен через nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/GostCryptography

Comment: @Vein а под core не видели?

Comment: Нет, только подпись для СМЭВ используя криптопро (github.com/burcevsemyon/Smev3Sharp/tree/dev) включая linux 

можно добавить обвязки к апи криптопро для шифрования и реализовать нужные методы самому

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал все гораздо проще зашифровал и подписал документы используя утилиту cryptcp.x64 с установленным крипто-про. Запускается через process.Start